# Android WorkManager Network Constraint For Both Wifi and Data (Cellular)

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-workmanager, android-networking

I am learning `WorkManager` and wondering if following the correct way of setting network constraint for both Wifi and data (cellular):

```
val constraints = Constraints.Builder().run {
    setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.UNMETERED)    //Wifi
    setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.METERED)      //data
    build()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's exactly the use case for the [`NetworkType.CONNECTED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/NetworkType#CONNECTED) type:

> Any working network connection is required for this work.